# JAAS, JSF 2 and Authentication

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, authentication, jaas, glassfish-4

I want to build a web application with JSF where I use JAAS for authentication.
I will run the application on Glassfish v4 and I want to use a custom realm/login module to have my user credentials stored in a database and moreover having the passwords salted and hashed. As far as I know the JDBCRealm of Glassfish does not give me possibility to have the passwords salted.
I already found resources on how build such login modules and security realms for it.

Now I reached a point where I still have too many questions open and no answers found on the web.

My first question now is more like a conceptual question.

So for me it actually seems like a disadvantage if I use JAAS since that would require me to write custom realms and login modules for each application server I want my application to be deployed to.
I mean I see the advantage to have the authentication seperated but still it seems quite a bit of extra work compared to a solution where I would do the login procedure on my own.
Since I could also do the access control using custom filter in JSF this seems to be a more universal way because there is no extra effort when I change the application server.
Do I miss something here?

This also leads me to another point. Is there a way to perform the login procedure by myself but assign the current user specific roles in the context of JAAS during my custom login?

Another question: I have seen that it is also possible to create/update/delete users with a custom realm which sounds awesome for my needs... Sorry if this is a kind of a noob question but I still could not figure out how to retrieve the JAAS realm from within my JSF application...